# How to replace a Character in text By jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to replace a charcter within a text 
For instance

```
 <script>alert("Hi i am nishant");</script>
```

here i want to replace < and > by ASCII code so how i will replace it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var text = text.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```